# Jquery File Upload Delete File Programmatically

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm trying to prevent Jquery fileupload delete until a Bootbox modal popup is answered by the user.

I tried catching fileuploaddestroy and running e.preventDefault() , which works to prevent the delete.
But how can I trigger the delete once the user presses OK?  I have the "data" object with the delete URL from handling the event.

I tried to call the destroy function directly, but it's not working.  the "that" parameter doesn't seem to initialize properly.  Also since the event was prevent defaulted, I created a new event..

```
    var ev = jQuery.Event( "click" );
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option').destroy(ev, data);
```

I get

```
jquery.fileupload-ui.js:399 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I'm looking for a way to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Sorry, haven't figured out a way yet.  I wish someone from the Jquery Fileupload team would respond.  I've looked through their code to try to figure out some way, but I have no idea why I can't call .destroy() directly still.

Comment: No problem. I finally settled on hiding the delete button with css and creating a button that launches the bootstrap modal and sets the value of a hidden input with the filename. When someone clicks the accept button in the modal, I trigger a click event on the hidden fileupload button where the filename matches the one in the hidden input. It's not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this assuming myAsyncConfirm is an async confirm library that will call the passed function on confirmation.

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddestroy', function (e, data) {
  myAsyncConfirm(
    'Are you sure you want to delete file?',
    function() {
      $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'destroy').call($('#fileupload'), $.Event('destroy'), data);
    });
  return false;
});
```